# Stack Trace in Codeblock

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am using Codeblocks for the first time to run a cpp program. While compling the program an error occurs, I want to know the line number from the program where the error is evoking or in other words I want to see the stack trace of the program.

How can achieve this?

Comment: While compiling or running your code? Stack traces usually occur when your crashed at runtime.

Comment: Stack traces are a run-time concept, if your program isn't running there is no stack to trace. The compile-time error message should include the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gdb. To debug, compile with g++ and -g at the end of the command and then run your program with gdb (in linux, `gdb ./NameOfYourProgram`). Then, you type `r` to run it, and when an error occurs, just type `where` and you get the stack. You can also set breakpoints and perform steps with gdb to examine the bug further.